# RoR: Stack level too deep with after create method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the the following after create method in my record model that keeps throwing an Stack level too deep error every time i try creating a new record:

```
class record

  has_many :authorizations
  has_many :roles, :through => :authorizations, :dependent => :destroy, :primary_key => :record_secondary_id

  after_create :new_record

  def create_roles
    self.roles.create :name => "#{self.record_title} edit", :record_id => self.id, :edit => true, :review => false
    self.roles.create :name => "#{self.record_title} review", :record_id => self.id, :edit => false, :review => true
  end

  def set_secondary_id
      self.update_attribute :record_secondary_id, self.id
  end

  def new_record
    if self.record_secondary_id.blank?
      set_secondary_id
      create_roles
    end
  end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem might be coming from the following call:

```
 has_many :authorizations
 has_many :roles, :through => :authorizations, :dependent => :destroy, :primary_key => :record_secondary_id
```

change that to:

```
  has_many :authorizations, :dependent => :destroy, :primary_key => :record_secondary_id
  has_many :roles, :through => :authorizations
```

that should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are having infinite recursion between create record and create_roles.

You need to create role with the record itself instead of callback. 
It will be easy as you are using has_many through relationship.

Edited:

In your controller,

```
@record = Record.new(params[:record])
@role1 = Role.new('some_params')
@role2 = Role.new('some_params')
@record.roles = [@role1, @role2]
@record.save
```

Comment: how do i do that? im very new to rails. Thanks

Comment: thanks for the updated answer, is there no way this can be done in the model?

Comment: i also tried out having that in the controller and i get the same error, stack level too deep.

Comment: yes i did, it still gave the same problem, please check Mo's answer for reason it wasn't working, seems like i had the associations set up wrong.